# GIt - Should a new file from a new branch appear as an untracked change on the master?

Tags: git

I am getting my feet wet with git, and wondered if this was an expected behaviour, or if I have done something wrong.

I have a repo, and have created a branch in order to develop twitter integration. When I switch back to the master branch the files needed for the twitter integration (which should only appear in the twitter branch) appear as an untracked change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started editing your *working copy* whilst on your branch, and then you ran `git checkout master` without actually committing your changes.

When you run `git checkout` with changes in your *working copy*, Git switches to the new branch and takes the changes in the working copy with it. (If a file in your working copy were to differ in both branches, Git won't let you switch branches.)

This is standard Git behaviour. In order to do what you expected, you can simply switch back to your branch and commit the changes:

```
$ git checkout branch

$ git add .

$ git commit
```

Comment: `git checkout` doesn't by default merge changes. If you have local modifications to a file which differs between the two branches, it refuses to switch branches. If you want it to merge, pass the `-m, --merge` option. (Your explanation's otherwise correct though!)